# referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, pygame

i have the following code to create a pygame of snake ( very basic ), to increase my snakes length i added a statement saying `snakeLength += 1 in line 142` it comes up with an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python27/sjewgou.py", line 142, in <module>
       gameLoop()
      File "C:/Python27/sjewgou.py", line 118, in gameLoop
       if len(snakeList) > snakeLength:
     UnboundLocalError: local variable 'snakeLength' referenced before assignment
```

what do i do ?

my code is as follows

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import time
import random

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

block_size = 10
FPS = 30

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ssssrikar")

gameExit = False
lead_x = display_width/2
lead_y = display_height/2

lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

snakeList = []
snakeLength = 1


font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)

def snake(block_size,snakelist):
    for elements in snakelist:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [elements[0], elements[1],block_size,block_size])



def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])



def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0        


    randAppleX = round(random.randrange(0,display_width-block_size)/10.0)*10.0
    randAppleY = round(random.randrange(0,display_height-block_size)/10.0)*10.0



    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Gamer over, press C to play again or Q to quit",red)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change = block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0

        if lead_x >= display_width:
            gameOver = True
        elif lead_x < 0:
            gameOver = True
        elif lead_y >= display_height:
            gameOver = True
        elif lead_y < 0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change

        lead_y += lead_y_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [randAppleX,randAppleY,block_size,block_size])



        snakeHead = []
        snakeHead.append(lead_x)
        snakeHead.append(lead_y)
        snakeList.append(snakeHead)

        if len(snakeList) > snakeLength:
            del snakeList[0]

        snake(block_size, snakeList)



        pygame.display.update()

        if lead_x == randAppleX and lead_y == randAppleY:
            randAppleX = round(random.randrange(0,display_width-block_size)/10.0)*10
            randAppleY = round(random.randrange(0,display_height-block_size)/10.0)*10
            snakeLength += 1


        clock.tick(FPS)





    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

UnboundLocalError, means your variable is not defined in scope of function.

in you game loop add

```
global snakeLength
```

example:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def foo():
...     x += 1        #here x is local to foo
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

>>> def foo():
...     global x    # now x is global variable
...     x += 1
... 
>>> foo()
>>> x
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `global snakeLength` in the function where you reference `snakeLength`.

Comment: This answer is preferable over `global`.

Answer (score 0):

you used **snakeLength += 1**   befor assigning any value to **snakeLengh**

for example:

```
a + = 1
```

can use when **a** has some value like a=0 or a =10 .......etc

```
correct way

a = 0
a +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it work putting at the beginning of the game loop

```
global snakeLength
```

This indicates python that the variable is in the global namescape. Here you can find more information about it and explains cases where this maybe will not work as the dirty patch it is

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python